# Windows 10 - launch and position applications upon startup

Tags: windows-10, application-launch

In windows 10, every time, I startup the computer. I launch 3 applications (2 chrome browsers and 1 visual studio) and position them in a certain place on my monitor. 
Instead of doing it manually every single time, how do I automate it so I could launch them upon startup from cold boot or reboot. 
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You may use a [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) script.

The script is stored in a `.ahk` file and it will look like this:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "myfile.txt"
WinWait, "myfile.txt"
WinMove, 100, 200, 300, 400
```

Repeat the last three lines with modifications as required.

References :

- [AutoHotkey documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm)
- [The Run command](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm)
- [The WinWait command](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm)
- [The WinMove command](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can place shortcuts in the same "Startup" folder as previous versions:

`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\`

It is not shown in the Start Menu itself, but in the Startup tab of Task Manager.

That will start the applications. Most applications restore their window positions on startup, assuming the virtual display size is the same. If not... you'll need a 3rd party solution. Something that resizes windows based on title, or something like that.

Comment: I have googled for 3rd party solution but can not find one. thanks

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner I ran into this [window layout manager](http://www.stefandidak.com/windows-layout-manager/) while writing [my own](https://github.com/nearwood/windmill) (shameless plug). It may be useful to you.

Answer (score -1):

Just do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=je_Ty9kpunM
It is free and worked for me very well!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1169571)